# Can it be disadvantageous to store jQuery objects in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chaining, performance

I've just recently asked the folloiwng question with regard to jQuery chaning:

[Is there a preferred way of formatting jQuery chains to make them more readable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286829/is-there-a-preferred-way-of-formatting-jquery-chains-to-make-them-more-readable)

A number of people replied with the suggestion that maybe I reduced the amount of chaining within the statement, and instead stored objects in holding variables, which makes sense to me.

However, my understanding is that the objects within a chain are already held on a stack (of sorts), so is the caching/storing of the results in a variable not effectively re-storing it, using more memory?

A comment on one of the posts seemed to indicate that there might not be too much of a performance hit (if any), so I would be happy to cache as suggested if it would be much more readable.

And also, if we are using caching, does this not then start limiting the usefulness of `.end()` and `.andSelf()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Objects are generally stored as references - pointers to locations in memory. Two variables both holding the same object don't duplicate all of the object's data - they just both hold pointers to the same location in memory where the actual object data is located. Thus, storing the object in a variable won't have much of a performance hit at all; nothing significant.

Comment: Interesting. So if I cast a number to a string - String(number), would this be a reference as well?

Comment: No. String(123) returns a string literal, not an object - thus there's no reference involved. If you wanted a String object, you'd need `new String(123)` instead, to create a new String object with contents of '123'.

Comment: Note that new String(123) still returns a literal and there is still no reference involved. Not sure that was clear. Only Objects, Arrays and Functions can be pointers.

Comment: @mwilcox: not true. Try the following: `var a = String('123');a.test="blah";alert(a.test);` and then compare it with `var a = new String('123');a.test="blah";alert(a.test);` - you'll see that the former pops up "undefined", while the latter pops up "blah".

Answer (score 5):

Adding to @Dav's answer, there are times when storing jquery objects in variables will be a good thing. Classic example:

```
$('#something div').each( function() {
    $(this).css({'background-color':'#afa'});
    // do some stuff;
    $(this).slideDown('fast');
}
```

Better way:

```
$('#something div').each( function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css({'background-color':'#afa'});
    // do some stuff;
    $this.slideDown('fast');
}
```

This way you avoid *creating* jquery objects whenever you call `$`.