# Indenting/breaking jquery chains for readability

Tags: javascript, jquery, readability, chaining

I'm curious as to how other people indent/break long jQuery chains, as I can never decide what is more readable (particularly when using .end() to "close" a block of methods e.g.

```
$(this).not(":has(.pointer)").append(pointerHtml)
                .end()
            .closest("li").toggleClass("selected")
            .siblings().removeClass("selected")
            .andSelf().removeClass("pre-selected")
                .end().end()
            .filter(".selected").prev().addClass("pre-selected");
```

How would YOU format this?

Comment: I like this question, but it's just inherently subjective.  It might make a good CW discussion, or else perhaps a good one on Programmers.

Comment: I was going to ask if it was still possible to tag a question as "opinion" on here as I coudln't see how

Comment: Wow - that was a swift closure. Point taken that this is a subjective question, but to close it so rapidly because it's *likely* to end up in an almighty spat seems a bit too pessimistic to me. Most questions about good practice in writing code (which is what this question, in essence, is about) are subjective to some degree, and it's a shame that the stackoverflow community won't be able to voice their opinions on this. (*edit* Reposted on Programmers as soon as was suggested - question views so far: 0)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1286829/277335

Answer (score -1):

```
$(this).not(":has(.pointer)")
           .append(pointerHtml)
           .end()
           .closest("li")
           .toggleClass("selected")
           .siblings()
           .removeClass("selected")
           .andSelf()
           .removeClass("pre-selected")
           .end()
           .end()
           .filter(".selected")
           .prev()
           .addClass("pre-selected");
```